# Code signing identifier issue on Xcode4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I downloaded a distribution provision from Apple website and I added developer certification and distribution certification in my keychain. Of course, I added provisions to organizer.

However, in Xcode4, build settings tab, Code signing section, there is just a text field and no options to choose my provisions. I can't believe that!

So, if somebody has the answer, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Project > Build Settings what do you have the 'Configuration' dropdown at the top set to? If it's 'Simulator' I believe the code signing option will be blank or won't show.

Try setting it to 'Distribution' if it's not already and see if that work.

Hope that helps.